# Erro ao conectar no PostgreSQL pelo pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Instalei o `pgAdmin 4` no meu note com `Windows 10` e não estou conseguindo acessar o banco de dados.

> Host name/address = /198.22.33.44
>   Porta 5432
>   Maintenance Database = xxxxxx
>   Username = cesar_r
>   Password = ******
>   SSL mode = Prefer

O nº do IP está configurado no **pg_hba.conf** da seguinte forma:

> host all all 198.22.33.44/32 password

No endereço coloco o nº do IP precedido de / (conforme consta na documentação).
O banco está instalado num servidor Linux (Ubuntu).

OBS: Estou tentando conectar com um usuário simples com permissão somente de leitura.

Comment: Que erro que ele acusa?

Comment: No pgAdmin 4 é necessário indicar o diretório dos binários, você fez isso? como já disse que é Windows 10 é provável que seja `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\*versao*\bin`. Precisamos saber qual é o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Deu um trabalhinho pra rodar... mas é o seguinte, após instalar o pgAdmin4

Num prompt cmd (não serve do git bash) acesse o diretório do postgres

```
cd c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\SUA_VERSAO\bin
```

Rode o init

```
initdb -D "c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data"
```

Inicie o pg  definindo um diretório para o log

```
pg_ctl -D "c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/data" -l "C:/Users/SEU_USUARIO/logfile.log" start
```

Pronto. O usuário que você usou na instalação deve ser usado para criar o servidor no pgAdmin4

caso esteja na dúvida sobre o user cadastrado, digite ainda no prompt:

```
createuser
```

Ele vai informar o nome já existente.